# Start a 2013 site workflow from another workflow

Tags: workflow, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, workflow2013

I have seen here several discussion about how to trigger a 2013 list workflow using REST, but so far I cannot succeed in running a **site workflow**, which should be basically easier. My code:

```
https://mysite.sharepoint.com/mysite/_api/SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowInstanceService.Current/StartWorkflow(subscriptionId='0fa223dc-898e-493e-b523-c89ba796688b')
```

returns a BadRequest. The subscriptionId is correct and the WF called is a site workflow without parameter.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is only a workaround: **move all actions in the list workflow** I wanted to use to launch the site workflow. It works perfectly (of course after re-configuring all parameters).

Comment: Can you explain this in more detail? Do you mean that you ended up moving all your Site WF's actions into a new List WF instead?

Comment: @ChrisOdegard, yes, I have created a plain list workflow and copied all actions there

Answer (score -1):

Try this site  "Create a SharePoint 2013 workflow to start the site workflow" http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sharepoint-2013/sharepoint-designer-2013-workflow-start-another-workflow.htm

Comment: This is valid only for 2010 site workflows